# Copy and paste the row a N number of times (N based on a value in the cell)

Tags: vba, excel

I've read many similar threads but I still can't figure out how to adjust my code.

I have a code that copies a range and pastes it ONCE in the Data tab.

I would like the range to copy a n number of times based on the numerical value in cell F12 of the sheet "NoOfRowsToPaste". What should I add to the code to perform this?

```
Sub UpdateLogWorksheet()

        Dim historyWks As Worksheet
        Dim inputWks As Worksheet

        Dim nextRow As Long
        Dim oCol As Long

        Dim myCopy As Range
        Dim myTest As Range

        Dim lRsp As Long

        Set inputWks = Worksheets("Input")
        Set historyWks = Worksheets("Data")
        oCol = 3 ' staff info is pasted on data sheet, starting in this column

        'check for duplicate staff number in database
        If inputWks.Range("CheckAssNo") = True Then
          lRsp = MsgBox("Order ID already in database. Update record?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Duplicate ID")
          If lRsp = vbYes Then
            UpdateLogRecord
          Else
            MsgBox "Please change Order ID to a unique number."
          End If

        Else

          'cells to copy from Input sheet - some contain formulas
          Set myCopy = inputWks.Range("Entry")

          With historyWks
              nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
          End With

          With inputWks
              'mandatory fields are tested in hidden column
              Set myTest = myCopy.Offset(0, 2)

              If Application.Count(myTest) > 0 Then
                  MsgBox "Please fill in all the cells!"
                  Exit Sub
              End If
          End With

          With historyWks
              'enter date and time stamp in record
              With .Cells(nextRow, "A")
                  .Value = Now
                  .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
              End With
              'enter user name in column B
              .Cells(nextRow, "B").Value = Application.UserName
              'copy the data and paste onto data sheet
              myCopy.Copy
              .Cells(nextRow, oCol).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
              Application.CutCopyMode = False
          End With

          'clear input cells that contain constants
          ClearDataEntry
      End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good answer from Thomas, though if you wanted to do additional logic for different rows I'd implement a loop and build the logic in. Providing just in case.

```
Sub UpdateLogWorksheet()

        Dim historyWks As Worksheet
        Dim inputWks As Worksheet

        Dim nextRow As Long
        Dim oCol As Long

        Dim myCopy As Range
        Dim myTest As Range

        Dim lRsp As Long

        Set inputWks = Worksheets("Input")
        Set historyWks = Worksheets("Data")

        Dim lng As Long
        Dim pasteCount As Long
        pasteCount = Worksheets("NoOfRowsToPaste").Cells(12, 6)

        oCol = 3 ' staff info is pasted on data sheet, starting in this column

        'check for duplicate staff number in database
        If inputWks.Range("CheckAssNo") = True Then
          lRsp = MsgBox("Order ID already in database. Update record?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Duplicate ID")
          If lRsp = vbYes Then
            UpdateLogRecord
          Else
            MsgBox "Please change Order ID to a unique number."
          End If

        Else

          'cells to copy from Input sheet - some contain formulas
          Set myCopy = inputWks.Range("Entry")

          With historyWks
              nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
          End With

          With inputWks
              'mandatory fields are tested in hidden column
              Set myTest = myCopy.Offset(0, 2)

              If Application.Count(myTest) > 0 Then
                  MsgBox "Please fill in all the cells!"
                  Exit Sub
              End If
          End With

        With historyWks
            'enter date and time stamp in record
            For lng = 1 To pasteCount
                With .Cells(nextRow + lng, "A")
                    .Value = Now
                    .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
                End With
                'enter user name in column B
                .Cells(nextRow + lng, "B").Value = Application.UserName
                'copy the data and paste onto data sheet
                myCopy.Copy
                .Cells(nextRow + lng, oCol).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
            Next lng
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With

          'clear input cells that contain constants
          ClearDataEntry
      End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Zerk, thanks very much, when you say logic, what do you mean by it? When I copy these X (e.g. 12) number of rows, I would like one column to be customised. This means copying X (e.g. 12) number of cells above B14 (including B14) from sheet  "NoOfRowsToPaste". In this case, would your code work better?

Comment: Both methods would work. the advantage of Thomas's way is it's short, clean, and fast. The loop method i showed has more worksheet transactions in this manner but you could do extra things such as additional calculations/derived values for each cell if you wanted to and treat rows differently to each other.

Comment: Thanks Zerk. I decided to use yours in case I need to do more complicated things in the future. I will try to figure out the latter action following this question and if I can't figure out myself, I'll be asking the forum again :)

Answer (score 1):

Resizing the number of rows in the target range will correctly duplicate the copied data.

```
n = Worksheets("NoOfRowsToPaste").Range("F12").Value
.Cells(nextRow, oCol).Resize(n).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
```